# Selenium IDE automation seems to break JavaScript window

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using selenium IDE (currently available only on firefox) to do some automated testing of a site I'm coding. When selenium navigates to, a form filling page, and fills in the info - a 'window.alert()' is called by a button. 
When using selenium my set of commands look like this:

```
open /
clickAndWait document.form1.Action[1]
select stuff 
type stuff 
   etc, etc
click name=myPreview
```

---

When I click through recording this the first time, it works no problem. When I rerun the script `window.alert` and `alert` don't work from the console or anything. I've debugged it, and its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `window.alert()` is called as part of a selenium script (I'm talking at least in the IDE), it is called even though a user watching does not see an alert pop up. According to the documentation:

> Under Selenium, JavaScript alerts will NOT pop up a visible alert
>   dialog.
>
> Selenium does NOT support JavaScript alerts that are generated in a
>   page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be
>   generated and Selenium will hang until someone manually clicks OK.

Both `assertAlert` and `verifyAlert` are both based off `getAlert()`, all of which do the alert 'stuff' in the background. So try adding these functions to ensure that the alert is working, run the script, and then check to see if it works.

A note: this only works if you ensure the test fails before you put in the alert (basic idea of testing, fail first - make test pass).